# How can I call a deployed smart contract on Kovan using Python?

Tags: remix, contract-invocation, web3.py, python, kovan

The smart contract was written and deployed on Kovan using Remix IDE and injected Metamask Kovan test network account. However, I'll need python to deal with large input of a function in the smart contract. How can I do this? I have tried to register an Infura account and use it to interact with the function, the python code runs smoothly, but I can't see any changes to the smart contract. So I'm wondering how I can realize this goal. Thanks in advance.

My code logic is as follows.

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://kovan.infura.io/v3/...(my address)'))
ctr = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi) # address and abi are both specified previously
ctr.functions.my_func(input).call()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any smart contract call cannot change the Ethereum state.

You need to perform a transaction and pay the gas fee to make any state changes. There are no free state changes.

Use `transact()` instead of `call()`. [You will also need to set up a local private key](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#read-a-private-key-from-an-environment-variable).